# terms query does not support minimum_match in Elasticsearch 2.3.3

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search documents which match at least two key words using terms query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
     "terms": {
        "title": ["java","编程","思想"],
        "minimum_match": 2
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
       "title": {}
    }
  }
}
```

It returns "terms  query does not support  minimum_match".What's wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct name was `minimum_should_match` and that setting has been [deprecated in ES 2.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/breaking_20_query_dsl_changes.html#_literal_terms_literal_query_and_filter).

What you can do instead is to use a `bool/should` query with three `term` queries and the `minimum_should_match` setting for `bool/should` queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 2,
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "title": "java"
           }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "title": "编程"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "title":  "思想"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "title": {}
    }
  }
}
```