# ElasticSearch filter by multiple keywords

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

In **ElasticSearch 6.8** I have indexed many documents that contains a collection of tags. The tags are mapped as `keyword`.

```
"tags": {
    "type": "keyword"
},
```

When doing

```
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : { "match" : { "name" : "beach" } },
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { "tags" : ["games", "cars"]  }
        }
    }
}
```

I get documents that contains at least one of those tags. But I want to filter out all documents that **do not** contains ALL the given tags.

I tried

```
"query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : { "match" : { "name" : "beach" } },
        "filter" : {
            "terms" : { 
              "tags" : ["games", "cars"], 
              "minimum_should_match": 2 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it throws an error: `"[terms] query does not support [minimum_should_match]"`

Which would be the correct way of filtering out documents that do not contain those two tags? Note that the real query may contain other "should" clauses as well.

Comment: Not sure if this is a homework - but the hint is in the question _"should"_. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40837678/terms-query-does-not-support-minimum-match-in-elasticsearch-2-3-3)